# Limit ransack output by textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I've started use ransack gem for filtering my database. But I cannot find out how can I define textfield which would define how many rows should display, e.g. I would enter 5 to my textfield and my output would display only 5 last results from database.

**controller:**

```
def index
    @q             = Roulette.search(params[:q])
    @numbers       = @q.result
end
```

**view:**

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :table_id_eq, "Table" %>
    <%= f.select :table_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Table.all, :id, :title, @q.table_id_eq), include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :woman_id_eq, "Woman" %>      
    <%= f.select :woman_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Woman.all, :id, :name, @q.woman_id_eq), include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>

<div id="numbers">
  <% @numbers.each do |no| %>
    <h4> <%= no.number %>,</h4>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#limit](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/limit) to limit the number of results returned in your controller.

```
 def index
     @q             = Roulette.search(params[:q]).limit(5)
     @numbers       = @q.result
 end
```

So you could pass a value from your textfield to your controller in the params hash, to be used by `limit`. Eg:

```
 @q = Roulette.search(params[:q]).limit(params[:no_of_results)
```

Comment: But I don't know how to pass a value to controller. If I add to view: 
<%= f.text_field :no_of_results %> I am getting error: undefined method `:no_of_results' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007fa4afb79a98>

Comment: You'll need to add `:no_of_results` to your model. You can add an attribute to your model. However, you probably want to use a [virtual attribute](http://hibbard.eu/using-virtual-attributes-in-rails-3/).

Comment: I finally find out how to pass parameter to controller. I had to create empty method  via:   
  ransacker :no_of_results do |r|
  end

Virtual attribute doesnt work because of ransack translates search parameters into queries probably.